# dynamically generate cmds in KubernetesPodOperator with Jinja2 template

Tags: airflow, jinja2, kubernetespodoperator

I have a conf json looks like this

```
{ "customer": "customer1",
  "region": "south"
}
```

I want generate a
cmds: ["aws", "domain_name", "etl_name", "--customer", "customer1", "--region", "south"]

The Jinja2 template I used:

```
task1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
image="....",
env_vars={...},
cmds=["aws", "domain_name", "etl_name",
"""'--customer', '{{ dag_run.conf.customer }}', '--region', '{{ dag_run.conf.region }}'""" 
)
```

I get the exact cmds `'--customer', 'customer1', '--region', 'south'`.

But when I run the code in airflow.
I saw `'--customer,' 'customer1,' '--region,' 'south'`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: add a little bit more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the jinja parameters as one string.

Separate each one in the command args.

```
    task1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
    image="....",
    env_vars={...},
    cmds=["aws", "domain_name","etl_name",
"--customer", "{{ dag_run.conf.customer }}", "--region","{{ dag_run.conf.region }}"])
```

Comment: Thanks, @ozs. A followup question. Can I add a if statement so there is different combination? When customer exists in conf then add it. when region exists in conf, then add it?

Comment: You can create a PythonOperator that return a list of your args (make all the logic with python code) and then in kube task pull it with ti.xcom_pull