# Airflow cmds template engine breaks my string

Tags: airflow, jinja2, dbt

I am passing some json string (from  Run w/Config) into my DAG, it's not working, then I try to directly hard-code a string to the operator input cmds =. The Dag is like

```
  
    dbt_1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
        config_file="/home/airflow/composer_kube_config",
        kubernetes_conn_id='kubernetes_default',
        name="dbt-name",
        image=f"gcr.io/my_proj/dbt-monitor-paid-media",
        cmds=['poetry','run','dbt','run','-s dbt_read_input --profiles-dir /home/appuser --project-dir /home/appuser/monitor_pm'],
        labels={"task": "dbt_scheules"},
        task_id="dbt_run_1",
        startup_timeout_seconds=300,
        container_resources=k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
            requests={"memory": "1G", "ephemeral-storage": "2G"},
        )
```

But the dbt command fails,  when I check Rendered Template, the cmds became:
['poetry',
'run',
'dbt',
'run',
' -s dbt_read_input --profiles-dir /home/appuser --project-dir '
'/home/appuser/monitor_pm']

Note the last string of cmds list become two quoted strings without comma separation.

While the log shows:

```
'containers': [{'args': None,
                          'command': ['poetry',
                                      'run',
                                      'dbt',
                                      'run',
                                      ' -s dbt_read_input --profiles-dir '
                                      '/home/appuser --project-dir '
                                      '/home/appuser/monitor_pm'],
                          'env': None,
```

I thought it could be template engine's issue about escape characters, so I tried to use '" or "' to surround the string, or use dag_run (run W/config), still couldn't find a workaround. Anyone has similar experiences? Thanks!

I expect to see

```
['poetry',
 'run',
 'dbt',
 'run',
 ' -s dbt_read_input --profiles-dir /home/appuser --project-dir /home/appuser/monitor_pm']
```

in Rendered Template.

Comment: Is it because my string is too long? I saw another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933509/dynamically-generate-cmds-in-kubernetespodoperator-with-jinja2-template.    But didn't see explanation